# WooCommerce Order Export save custom formats

Tags: php, wordpress, csv, woocommerce, export

I recently bought the WooCommerce Customer / Order CSV Export plugin for a WordPress webshop project at work. I am able to create a custom format, but there doesn't seem to be an option to save it so I can switch between multiple ones. Can this be done is some way?